# How do I disable Hardware Acceleration for "Windows Photo Viewer" in win 7?

Tags: windows-7, hardware-acceleration, windows-photo-viewer

I have difficulties with Hardware Acceleration (hardware failure, cannot be fixed) and I want to disable hardware acceleration for many apps, since win 7 does not support it with display drivers installed.

There is a program named "Windows Photo Viewer". It's the default program for image viewing. I am looking for a configuration or registry entries that will tell the program to avoid using hardware acceleration.  I have done this to many applications, even in Windows Live 2011, I am sure there is a way to do it!

Comment: I don't know for sure, but for something that lightweight it wouldn't surprise me if you COULDN'T do it.  You may be able to *globally* disable this though - could you provide info on your graphics adapter?

Comment: I have made my research on that but anyway, if you can help i would appreciate it. My card is Geforce Go 6150

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to disable hardware acceleration only for a single application, because the graphic pipeline used to render images is not implemented in the application but in your system.

I would suggest the following:

1. Try switching your interface to Windows Classic. That would render your graphics using GDI+ engine rather than DirectX.
2. Try using WindowsXP compatibility mode for selected application -- it might work.