# Force software rendering of OpenGL application on Windows

Tags: windows, gpu, gaming, graphics, opengl

I'm using a piece of software that uses OpenGL to render the 2D graphics, on my desktop and sometimes my laptop. The software is crashing frequently on my desktop but not on my laptop. My desktop has a dedicated ATI graphics card and I think the piece of software is not playing nicely with it.

**Is there a way to force software rendering for that application or applications that use OpenGL specifically?**

I know Windows does allow me to go *System > Display > Settings* and make change on a per application basis there but the only options are *Power saving* or *High performance* and my graphics card is the only device listed under both options.

Comment: Does that software have a setting with a name similar to "Hardware Acceleration" ?

Comment: See also [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/367665/how-do-i-disable-hardware-acceleration-for-windows-photo-viewer-in-win-7).

Comment: @harrymc the software unfortunately does not have a setting similar to "hardware acceleration" however the post you have linked to is helpful thank you.